# PHP - Exit preventing a pop up

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me the right way to do this. I want a pop up first, then the script to stop, but when I run this, the exit just overrides the pop up?

```
if (HandOverNotesModifiedTime > $datetime_from)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('WARNING: Notes have not been updated!');<script>";
    exit(header('Location:/handoverTESTING.html');
}
```

I tried without the exit, just to make sure the pop up works, and it does.

Comment: You can not create output _and_ redirect elsewhere at the same time, it is either-or.

Comment: Do the redirect in JavaScript: `alert('WARNING: Notes have not been updated!'); window.location.href = "/handoverTESTING.html";`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use like this :**

```
if (HandOverNotesModifiedTime > $datetime_from)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('WARNING: Notes have not been updated!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.assign('/handoverTESTING.html');</script>";
}
```

**Page redirection reason :**

*Popups are created on the client side, and the header redirection takes place on the server side.*

*PHP is executed at the server side. It renders HTML,Styles and sends it to the browser then browser execute the javascript codes*